# Error while trying to loop through mp4 video frames

Tags: python, opencv, video, ffmpeg, mp4

Im trying to make a python program that loops though all frames in an mp4 video but keep getter a weird response.
my code:

```
import cv2
video = cv2.VideoCapture('temp_vid.mp4')
video_frames = []



# loop over the frames of the video
while True:
    # grab the current frame
    (grabbed, frame) = video.read()
    video_frames.append(frame)
    
    # check to see if we have reached the end of the
    if not grabbed:
        break


print(len(video_frames))
```

My response

```
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Your platform doesn't suppport hardware accelerated AV1 decoding.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to get pixel format.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Missing Sequence Header.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to allocate space for current frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Get current frame error
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to allocate space for current frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Get current frame error
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to get reference frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to allocate space for current frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Get current frame error
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to get reference frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to allocate space for current frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Get current frame error
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to get reference frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to allocate space for current frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Get current frame error
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to get reference frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to allocate space for current frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Get current frame error
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to get reference frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to allocate space for current frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Get current frame error
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to get reference frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to allocate space for current frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Get current frame error
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to get reference frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to allocate space for current frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Get current frame error
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to get reference frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to allocate space for current frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Get current frame error
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to get reference frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to allocate space for current frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Get current frame error
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to get reference frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to allocate space for current frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Get current frame error
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to get reference frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to allocate space for current frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Get current frame error
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to get reference frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to allocate space for current frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Get current frame error
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to get reference frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to allocate space for current frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Get current frame error
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to get reference frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to allocate space for current frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Get current frame error
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to get reference frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to allocate space for current frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Get current frame error
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to get reference frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to allocate space for current frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Get current frame error
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to get reference frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to allocate space for current frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Get current frame error
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to get reference frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to allocate space for current frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Get current frame error
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to get reference frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to allocate space for current frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Get current frame error
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to get reference frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to allocate space for current frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Get current frame error
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to get reference frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to allocate space for current frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Get current frame error
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to get reference frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to allocate space for current frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Get current frame error
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to get reference frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to allocate space for current frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Get current frame error
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to get reference frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to allocate space for current frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Get current frame error
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to get reference frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to allocate space for current frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Get current frame error
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to get reference frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to allocate space for current frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Get current frame error
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to get reference frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to allocate space for current frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Get current frame error
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to get reference frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to allocate space for current frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Get current frame error
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to get reference frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to allocate space for current frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Get current frame error
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to get reference frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to allocate space for current frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Get current frame error
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to get reference frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to allocate space for current frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Get current frame error
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to get reference frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to allocate space for current frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Get current frame error
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to get reference frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] video_get_buffer: image parameters invalid
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Failed to allocate space for current frame.
[av1 @ 00000186be4456c0] Get current frame error
[av1 @ 00000186be444e40] Your platform doesn't suppport hardware accelerated AV1 decoding.
[av1 @ 00000186be444e40] Failed to get pixel format.
```

I would like to have a list as the final output so I can easily loop through the frames as if they were images and then do some image-to-text stuff on them.

Any help greatly appreciated:)

Comment: `Missing Sequence Header` sounds strange. Download  a **hex editor** to see the file bytes, then paste the first 4 lines here (from hex codes on left side, not the UTF text on the right side)... Looking at UTF/text view (is usually on the right side) you should see on first line `ftyp` and on second or third line it should have `moov` or `mdat`. If not then your file is not an MP4. That `moov` is the **header** that is possibly missing or corrupted.

Comment: not an opencv issue. you can reproduce this with plain ffmpeg. what wrote this file?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I used the pytube library to download a YouTube video the video is in 1080p and has no audio

Comment: I would say the file is corrupted. try `ffmpeg -i yourfile.mp4 -f null -`, which decodes the file and discards the decoded data... and also tells you if plain ffmpeg has trouble with the file in any way.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz This is the response with ffmpeg.exe:  video:31042kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown

Comment: I used this code to download it \n yt = pytube.YouTube(download_link)
YouTube(download_link).streams.filter(only_video=True,res = '1080p',file_extension='mp4').last().download(skip_existing = False,filename='temp_vid.mp4')